# ASV scan - What to expect from external scan services?

Tags: pci-dss

We've been asked to perform a vulnerability scan in our servers which process transactions with payment cards as a requirement for PCI compliance.
PCI DSS mandates this scan must be done by a ASV.

What should i expect from the result of this scan?

What type of scan does this scan correspond to?
Is it like a port scan like nmap scan?
Is it like a network services scan like nessus scan?
It it like a application vulnerability scan?
Is it a pentest?

Does ASV limit its service to only provide a cloud based security tool to identify vulnerabilities on your servers or does ASV help us to fix them?

Answer (score 3):

These are vulnerability scans which are more detailed and have more basic security information than a simple port scan. These are also not as detailed and don't dig nearly as deep as a full penetration test.

The ASV testing company may perform the test in a number of ways and having a portal to request a scan is not a requirement at all.

It could be considered a conflict of interest to have your ASV remediate your issues so this is not normally handled by the same company. The PCI DSS 3.1 mentions organizational independence in section 11.3.1.b of the PCI DSS
https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI_DSS_v3-1.pdf

You can learn more about ASV's from the PCI ASV Program Guide.
https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/pdfs/asv_program_guide_v1.0.pdf